# Spring Timers on JBoss don't stop when undeployed

Tags: spring, jboss, quartz-scheduler

I'm using the spring Quartz SchedulerFactoryBean to run a task (SimpleTriggerBean) every 10 seconds. It works great, except when I undeploy the app, the timer carries on running. The only way to stop it is to restart the server! Is there some JBoss or Spring configuration which will stop the timer when the app is undeployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - I was manually initialising the Spring Context without destroying it with the servlet. Added a listener, now it's all sorted.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue with the Spring Scheduler and destroying the context in a listener did the trick.  Example:

```
public class InitListener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {

    protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InitListener.class);
    protected static final ClassPathXmlApplicationContext springContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        "applicationContext.xml");;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        logger.info("Servlet Context is initialized....");
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        springContext.destroy();
        logger.info("Servlet Context is destroyed....");
    }
}
```